# Select Method find one below and one above using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Sorry if the question title may seem confusing. Basically I've created a list in MVC, which contains an ID, int Position and a string URL. With the list I want to be able to create a previous and next buttons, whilst using the list ID and position to get the buttons links.

If this makes no sense please let me know.

So basically once you click on a page, there will be a list of alternative pages, position will be created using a counter, Id will represent the page ID and the URL will be used for the buttons. I want to be able to use a linq or a c# statement that will be able to match the current page Id, with the page Id in the list, but then collect the item before and after using the position int value.

Here's my model

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public int Position { get; set; }
public string Url { get; set; }
```

That model is being used as a `List<overviewModel>`

This what i thought it might start with

```
var selectedItem = overviewModel.Select(x => x.Id == PageId);
```

The list output will look like this

```
[0] id=xxx1, position = 0, url = /1
[1] id=xxx2, position = 1, url = /2
[2] id=xxx3, position = 2, url = /3
[3] id=xxx4, position = 3, url = /4
```

Let say i go to page
`[1] id=xxx2, position = 1, url = /2`

the before values I want to pull through is 
`[0] id=xxx1, position = 0, url = /1`

the after values I want to pull through is 
`[2] id=xxx3, position = 2, url = /3`

Comment: I think you would be better of using indexing. Why do you want to force using linq?

Comment: Doesn't have to be a linq statement

Comment: @jsg Which parameter has value for `next` and `previous`? And also: Is the list sorted by this parameter?

Comment: No parameters, the next and previous will only need the url, position and id

Comment: Are those models held in certain sequence in the list ? List[0] is the prev page of List[1] and List[2] is the next page of List[1] ? And what is Position, a series of numbers from 0, 1, 2, 3, ... being well ordered ?

Comment: @jsg You missunderstood me. Next id? Next position? Next index in list? Next what? You cant say "next url position and id". That makes no sense.

Comment: So the list is created as, Overview[0] where position is 0, Overview[1] where position is 1. List[0] is the prev page of List[1] and List[2] is the next page of List[1] this would be correct, I will try to also implement a feature that will say if there is no next or previous then the buttons will be disabled

Comment: then how about `public OverviewModel Next { get { return overviewModels[selectedItem.Position+1]; } }`

Comment: @jsg Alright, so the list is sorted by the logic you understand as `next` and `previous`. Then the given answers should fit your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IndexOf method on a new list that has been sorted by your Position value to get the index of the current item and then add 1 for the next or substract one for the previous item:

```
List<overviewModel> sortedOverviewModelList = overviewModelList.OrderBy(item => item.Position).ToList();
overviewModel selectedItem = sortedOverviewModelList.Select(x => x.Id == PageId);
int index = sortedOverviewModelList.IndexOf(selectedItem);
int nextitem = index+1;
int previtem = index-1;
```

You should add some checks that the Indexes are still within the list's bounds.

Comment: This only works if his list is sorted by the value he understands as next and previous.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the fact that the class has a Position attribute which is used for sorting.

Comment: The issue im getting is the indexOf line is producing an error Error Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool>' to 'NavigationViewModel'

Comment: Please try specifiying explicit types. I edited the answer to reflect these changes. Seems that there is something wrong with the list types you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, you need something like this:

```
var list = new List<overviewModel>();
list.Add(new overviewModel() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Position = 3, Url = "url" });
list.Add(new overviewModel() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Position = 1, Url = "url" });
list.Add(new overviewModel() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Position = 4, Url = "url" });
list.Add(new overviewModel() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Position = 2, Url = "url" });
list.Add(new overviewModel() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Position = 5, Url = "url" });

var PageId = list[2].Id;

var triple = list.Where(e => e.Id == PageId).SelectMany(e => new[] 
           {
               list.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Position == e.Position - 1), 
               e, 
               list.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Position == e.Position + 1)
           }).ToArray();
```

OR, if some positions can be missed

```
    var triple = list.Where(e => e.Id == PageId).SelectMany(e => new[] 
           {
               list.Where(q => q.Position < e.Position).OrderBy(q => q.Position).LastOrDefault(), 
               e, 
               list.Where(q => q.Position > e.Position).OrderBy(q => q.Position).FirstOrDefault()
           }).ToArray();
```

As the result you'll get an array of 3 overviewModel items: the first one is the previous one (or null, if the selected item is the first one), then the selected item an then the next item (or null, if selected is the last).

Answer (score 0):

```
        int index = myList.IndexOf(selectedItem);
        var prev = index > 0 ? myList[index - 1] : selectedItem;
        var next = index < myList.Count ? myList[index + 1] : selectedItem;
```

Comment: This only works if his list is sorted by the value he understands as `next` and `previous`.